# jQuery href adding variables

Tags: php, jquery

I hope this is not a duplicate but I have not found it yet.

To be honest I found this method online and and cant find where I original found it or I would search there for the answer. The below is a test page I am testing my code.

My question is this how do I keep the clock value in the href and add the cellnumber to the href ?? Right now I get dropdowntest.php?cellnumber=8&?clock=8 which is the same value as the cellnumber I believe is in the line:

```
    + ['?cellnumber', $(this).val()].join('=') + ['&?clock', $(this).val()].join('=');
```

I have tried changing $(this) on the clock but I could not find the correct syntax.. below is all the code:

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        require('/db_connection/connect.db.php');
        require('settings.php');

        ?>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.clock').on('change', function() {

            location.href = location.href.split('?')[0]
                + ['?clock', $(this).val()].join('=');
            });



            $('.cellnumber').on('change', function() {
               location.href = location.href.split('?')[0]
                + ['?cellnumber', $(this).val()].join('=') + ['&?clock', $(this).val()].join('=');
            });



        });

        </script>

        <?php

        $clock = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username FROM user WHERE wocreate = 1 and hide = 1");
        echo "<select class='clock' name='clock' style='width:200px'>"; 
        echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($clock)){        
            echo "<option value='".$row['username']."''>".$row['username']."</option>"; 
        }
        echo "</select>";
        if (isset($_GET['clock'])) {
            $_SESSION['clock'] = $_GET['clock'];
            echo "<p></p>";
            echo 'Person Requesting Ticket is '.$_SESSION['clock'].'';
            echo "<p></p>";
        }
        ?>

        <?php
        echo "<br>"; 
        $cellnumbers = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT location FROM machinenumber WHERE status = 1 ");
        echo "<select class='cellnumber' name='cellnumber' style='width:200px'>"; 
        echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cellnumbers)){        
            echo "<option value='".$row['location']."''>".$row['location']."</option>"; 
        }
        echo "</select>";
        if (isset($_GET['cellnumber'])) {
            $_SESSION['cellnumber'] = $_GET['cellnumber'];
            echo "<p></p>";
            echo 'Person Requesting Ticket is '.$_SESSION['clock'].'';
            echo "<br>"; 

            echo 'Cell '.$_SESSION['cellnumber'].' is the location';
            echo "<p></p>";
        }
        ?>



        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['cellnumber'])) {
            $cellnumber=$_GET['cellnumber'];
            echo "<h3>Choose Machine Number</h3>";
            $machinenumber = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT number FROM machinenumber WHERE location =".$cellnumber." ;");
            echo "<select class='machinenumber' name='machinenumber' style=width:200px>"; 
            echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($machinenumber)) {        
                echo "<option     value='".$row['number']."'>".$row['number']."</option>"; 
            }
            echo "</select>";
        }
        ?>
```